# Autofil columns in one sheet from another only if columns have data AND a specific column has a specific value in Google Sheets

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language

I have a google sheet that autofills rows from another sheet only if the value is a specific column is "approved".

```
=FILTER(Responses!A:AAC,Responses!D:D="Approved")
```

Is it possible to combine this to somehow only display columns that aren't blank. So for example if row 1 Column D is "approved", column E is blank, and column F is "data", then the sheet will autopopulate row 1 column D and F but not E. THank you!

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Mb1EKVx7MEIPoDW-MypwAfgV6UIuXTThDBvk0AwCv9I/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 FILTER(Responses!A:AAC, Responses!D:D="Approved")), 
 "where Col2 is not null", ))
```

---

### update:

```
=FILTER(FILTER(Responses!A:AAA, Responses!D:D="Approved"),
 TRIM(QUERY(FILTER(Responses!A2:AAA, Responses!D2:D="Approved"),,9^9))<>"")
```

[image]

Comment: It autofilled everything that was approved but it also included the blank columns.